# Visual Studio 2015 - MSI project unsupported

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, vsinstaller

This VS2015 solution has two MSI projects, 32-bit and 64-bit. I have downloaded the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects#qna

But still I get a message about unsupported projects when trying to reload the MSI-projects.

[image: Unsupported project when Reload project]

Comment: The error message is accurate, that is not a supported Setup project.  The add-in brings back support for legacy .vdproj files.  An .isproj requires InstallShield.

Comment: Thx. That pointed me in the right direction. Although the instructions on this page indicates the VS Installer Projects as the solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx.
But after creating a new project for InstallShield, I got to the download page from Flexera Software. Post an answer and I'll give you the credit.